# laravel breeze component not showing content

Tags: laravel-breeze

Im using laravel with breeze, in the dasboard view i cant see the content with the default message
What could be the problem?

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 text-gray-900">
                    {{ __("You're logged in!") }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it was missing to place the slot directive in the main layout app.blade.php

```
<main>
        @yield('content')
        {{ $slot ?? ''}}
</main>
```